# Is it justifiable to downvote a subjective quesiton that seems to be stirring up debate?

Tags: discussion

New "anonymous" user (user12345678...) asks a question that requests a subjective "which approach is better" type question and then seems to be debating with the answers received?

E.g. [When/if to make a non-virtual function a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901441/when-if-to-make-a-non-virtual-function-a-member-function?noredirect=1#comment38685547_24901441)

Or am I doing the wrong thing?

Comment: And yet we have people saying "these questions don't stir up debate what are you talking about"

Comment: Flag as opinion based?

Comment: Flag/vote to close as opinion based seems right to me.

Comment: Never leave comments explaining you downvote when you see a debate going on, you might end up recieving unexpected downvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can downvote it if you like and if it feels right to you, but the more important thing is that the question gets closed, as subjective questions are off-topic for the *very* reason that they could stir up debate, which, as you may have seen, is exactly what's happening there (although to be fair, C++ questions tend to generate *tons* of back-and-forth comments in general).

I've closed the question so you don't have to flag it now, but in future, you'll want to flag subjective questions for closure, under "it should be closed for another reason..." followed by "primarily opinion-based". When you have 3000 reputation you will be able to [cast your own close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).